# Объявление члена-функции специализации шаблонного класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

При компиляции MySQL c `-std=c++20` получил следующую ошибку: *error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token*.

Проблемный участок кода:

```
template<std::size_t N>
class Bitmap { ... };

template<>
class Bitmap<64>
{
public:
    Bitmap<64>() { ... };
    //........^
};
```

Так как объявление полной специализации шаблонного класса идентично объявлению обычного класса, то и для объявления членов-функций специализации шаблонного класса должен быть использован обычный синтаксис:

```
template<>
class Bitmap<64>
{
public:
    Bitmap() { ... };
};
```

К сожалению, я не смог найти в стандарте "прямого" подтверждения (или опровержения) вышесказанному, поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

---

Я пробовал компилировать этот код GCC и Clang. Последний не выдает ошибок ни с C++17, ни с C++20. GCC с C++17 так же собирает код без ошибок.
Интересно, что изменение кода на:

```
template<>
class Bitmap
{
public:
    explicit Bitmap<64>() { ... };
};
```

приводит к тому, что и GCC перестает выдывать ошибки даже с `-std=c++20`. Это уже похоже на баг в компиляторе.

Comment: Все верно, вы написали шаблон класса Bitmap, и теперь пишете конструктор в его специализации, и  Bitmap<64> есть специализация Bitmap . То есть генерируется класс Bitmap(по главному шаблону) который зависит от  значения аргумента шаблона,  Если какой то компилятор не выдает ошибку, это  значит, что "он это как то переварил", но по стандарту это не правильно и  компиляторы имеют право  сообщать об этом.

Comment: тут даже дело  в требовании языка, а не стандарта

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, "но по стандарту это не правильно" - а не могли бы Вы указать, какой именно параграф говорит об этом?

Comment: Желание понятное:  но я не спец по стандарту, и как уже сказал, скорее это требование языка. В таких случая, лично я, не пытаюсь искать ответ в стандарте. Но в данном случаи  мне самому стало интересно что говорит стандарт об этом и говорит ли вообще?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, кажется, нашел; вынес в ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется, [данное описание изменений](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp17#class-2) отвечает на вопрос:

> **Affected subclauses:** [class.ctor] and [class.dtor]
> **Change:** A simple-template-id is no longer valid as the declarator-id of a constructor or destructor.
> **Rationale:** Remove potentially error-prone option for redundancy.
> **Effect on original feature:** Valid C++ 2017 code may fail to compile in this revision of C++. For example:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> struct A {
>   A<T>();           // error: simple-template-id not allowed for constructor
>   A(int);           // OK, injected-class-name used
>   ~A<T>();          // error: simple-template-id not allowed for destructor
> };
> ```

Т.е, С++20 требует использовать injected-имя класса для объявления конструктора\деструктора шаблона класса.

Comment: да, это как раз  и есть ответ